# How to make Html.ValidationMessageFor() render a DIV instead of a SPAN?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and I have a form that uses the following Html helper

```
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

When I look at the rendered Html that is produced in the browser it seems to render this as a **Span** element. This causes the validation message to be on the same line as one of my Labels.

What I want to know is how to make the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` method render a  **Div** element instead of a **Span**?

Comment: Wrap the @Html.ValidationMessageFor() in a div like this -> `<div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor()</div>`. Or you can make a HTML extension method that will wrap the span into a div, or use css.

Comment: Just use css to style it

Answer (score 6):

Add a parameter at last.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger newLine" },"div")
```

It will create a div.

[image]

Comment: This really answers the question "How to change SPAN to DIV"

Answer (score 4):

Instead of turning it into a div just add a style rule do the `ValidationMessageFor`:

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger newLine" })

.newLine 
{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside App_Start, where you can activate client-side-validation and unobtrusive, you can set the default element for the validation.

```
HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageElement = "div";
```